# error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip

Tags: printing, hplip

Whenever I try to print to an HP printer, I get a "Filter Failed" notice near the printer. "sudo service cups status" shows the following error message:

```
error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

```
$ sudo namei -l /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
```

returns:

```
f: /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root spool
drwx--x--- root lp   cups
drwxrwx--T root lp   tmp
drwxr-xr-x lp   lp   .hplip
```

Comment: Try the command: sudo touch /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip, and then run sudo service cups status

Comment: I see the same message in sudo service cups status

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `namei -l /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip`

Comment: @steeldriver done

Comment: There seem to be a number of related bug reports - but I can't tell from them what the problem (or solution) is exactly - sorry. See for example [HPLIP: Wrong permissions on /var/spool/cups](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1490321)

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that worked for me:

1. Reinstall hplip:

> ```
> sudo apt remove hplip
> sudo apt install hplip
> ```

2. Reinstall the printer **from the command line** (not from the Printers GUI):

> ```
> hp-setup -i
> n (=network printer)
> d (=download driver)
> ```

3. Remove the old printer from the Printers GUI.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second step?

Comment: I already elaborated as much as I could..

Answer (score 3):

I know I am kind of late, but maybe it helps someone. Running:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr
```

solved the issue (got the same error message out of nowhere) for my Epson XP-415, under Ubuntu 20.04.

After installation the printer was added automatically (its in the same network) and I was able to print from PDF without any problems.