# Installing the latest hplip runs into missing dependencies (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp

Trying to install the [latest stable version of hplip](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip) in the hope that it will solve [my trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051718/setting-up-hp-3788-wireless-printer/1053695), I get errors about missing libraries:

```
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: This installer cannot install 'libusb' for your distro/OS and/or version.
```

How can I install all the missing dependencies in their right versions?

Alternatively, would you recommend any other model/manufacturer for a low-cost printer that simply works with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: The answer you require is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078 This works well on my 18.04 system

Comment: Voted to close in favor of https://askubuntu.com/q/1173641/208696.

Comment: @matt what are you trying to do here? Why are you voting to close your own question as a dupe of your other question? Please pick _one_ question and delete the rest!