# Installing hplip 3.19.8 fails with errors about dependencies on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, hp

During the install, the installer doesn't recognize Ubuntu 18.04, so it asks me to tell it which OS and version I'm using.

After that, it finally fails with:

```
INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: This installer cannot install 'libusb' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

I have installed according to [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078)

output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe restricted multiverse main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe restricted multiverse main
```

Admittedly this is on an upgraded system not a clean install of 18.04.

I'm not sure whether installing `libusb` would not just lead to a cascade of additional missing dependencies ― before `libusb`, I already added (using apt) one missing dependency that it failed on with the same type of error message: `cups-devel`, by fiddling to gather that `libcups2-dev` contains `cups-devel`.

Installing `libusb` and `libusb-dev` didn't solve this error message, they are probably not the right package for what's missing.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Do you have correct repositories set? Please add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` to the question.

Comment: Added. They look pretty standard to me. I excluded some specific product entries for security reasons. Are you actually HP staff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest hplip version that's available for download just didn't turn out to work for me.

Switching to specifically using [the approach of using the apt managed version by the steps of this specific answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113686/208696), solved it. It seems that the plugin step is really necessary and not mentioned as part of the process in other places I've looked at.